# Mysql_real_escape_string не работает на другом хостинге

Tags: php

*mysql_real_escape_string* использую после соединения с бд. На старом хостинге всё работает нормально, а вот на новом получаю false. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Извини, но сегодня телепаты в отпуске.
Данные про старый хостинг, новый хостинг, пример использования функции - где это всё?

Comment: Прежде всего, mysql_real_escape_string устарела. А по сабжу - проверьте соединение с базой, т.е. устанавливается ли оно вообще.

Comment: На старом хосте PHP5.3, на новом 5.4 инфы о том что она устарела или как нибудь изменялась не нашёл, что использовать вместо неё?

Comment: Mysqli, PDO

Comment: @TANKIST вылазь из танка уже. Вот [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) в красной рамочке ты чего видишь ?

Comment: что? что? что?

Comment: @eicto ну блин библиотека pdo не маленькая, откуда мне знать. И да, спасибо:-)